# Can not I increase iter2 after erase the object iter2 pointed out previously?

Tags: c++, erase

the runtime error happens at the below line.
Could you explain why the error happens?
Can not I increase iter2 after erase the object iter2 pointed out previously?
iter2++;  ////  error happened

Best regards,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    vector <string> v;

    v.push_back("aaaa");
    v.push_back("bbbb");
    v.push_back("cccc");
    v.push_back("dddd");
    v.push_back("eeee");
    v.push_back("ffff");

    vector<string>::iterator iter2;

    iter2 = v.begin() + 2; 
    v.erase(iter2);
    iter2++;  ////  error happened  

    for (iter2 = v.begin(); iter2 != v.end(); iter2++) {
        cout << *iter2 << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: no, you cannot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase function has return value - iterator pointing to the next object in the container. So just use it like this:

```
iter2=erase(iter2);
```

Now you can increment it all you want.

Comment: Since the return value of `erase()` is already the next item of the vector, the increment should not be necessary anymore.

Comment: @harper, Yes, I made that point, just added that if futher incrementing is needed iter2 is valid iterator for that purpose.

Comment: How does this answer the question - "why the error happens"?

Comment: wow thanks a lot for  all of you answered my questions.